# Proving an integral doesn't converge

Tags: calculus, integration, ordinary-differential-equations, convergence-divergence, definite-integrals

I have derived a differential equation for the density of a gas due to gravity as a function of distance to the center of mass. However, in order to prove some properties about it, I need to know if a certain integral converges or diverges to infinity. The latter seems to be the case.

In this sense, given that
$$\rho'' = \dfrac{4\pi G}{RT}\rho^2 + \dfrac{(\rho')^2}{\rho}-\dfrac{2T+zT'}{zT}\rho'$$
(Where $\rho$ and $T$ are a function of $z$)
How do I prove that
$$\int^{\infty}_{0}x^2\rho(x)\mathrm{d}x$$
does not converge?

For simplicity, one may consider $T(z)$ as being constant

Comment: Is $R$ a constant, a variable, or a function of $z$? It appears to be the former in the given ODE, but the integral is with respect to $R$, leading me to suspect it may be one of the latter two.

Comment: It is a constant. I will change the $R$ in the integral to avoid confusion.

Comment: I would imagine one can try first to integrate from $0$ to $T$ and use integration by parts to bring in some derivatives.